# Stacked icons of network mounts on Desktop

Tags: 18.04, samba, filemanager

This might be just a cosmetic issue, but it is still quite annoying.
When I'm mounting multiple Samba network shares in ***Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop*** the icons that appear on the desktop are stacked on top of each other.

**Before mount**

This is what the desktop looks like before the network shares are mounted:
[image: Desktop before mount]

**Mounted drives in Files**

Then I use the **Files** GUI to mount the Samba network shares:
[image: Mounted drives in Files]

**After mount**

This is what the desktop looks like after the network shares are mounted:
[image: Desktop after mount]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I know two different, simple solutions:

1) start `gnome-tweaks` and disable the Mounted Volumes on the Desktop.

[image: gnome-tweaks]

2) right-click on the desktop and click: Organize Desktop by Name
Then it will sort the desktop and it will no longer be on top of each other.

[image: Disbale Icons]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If there are no more answers to my question I will probably use your solution number 1. Sorry, my OCD cannot accept solution 2 as I will still see the icons stacked for a short period of time :)

Comment: Also, I had to turn "Mounted Volumes" and not "Network Servers" in order for the icons to disappear.

Comment: I think it is a Bug which will somewhen get fixed