# Drives are invisible in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, filemanager

I have a really strange rare problem. I can't see my drives. They've disappeared and aren't accessible from File section. I always mount them to be visible and accessible on Desktop but when I clicked on File section at the left top corner to mount them couldn't see them.

**sudo fdisk -l | grep -v loop**

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D2FCEF5B-8752-4F65-A6EA-9749BD650D17

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   11995135  11993088   5.7G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p2  11995136   13033471   1038336   507M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3  13033472  208345087 195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 208345088  598970367 390625280 186.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5 598970368 1000214527 401244160 191.3G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add more information. What drives do you have, are they internal, external, USB, SATA, NVMe, hard or solid state? It is possible that they were improperly shut down/ removed and now they are corrupted. We can't tell unless you edit the question. Please open a terminal and enter the command `sudo fdisk -l`. It will ask for your password, but the cursor will not move when you enter it. This is normal. When you get the output copy the output of the command and paste it in the edited question. Then format the output with { } above the edit window.

Comment: @user68186 Sorry I'm a new user to Linux. I have ssd and I had couple of drives. I always mount them through File section but this time they're all invisible.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the question reopened. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: @TheMir It wasn't clear what you mean by "File section" so let me know if you are talking about the answer I just posted. Thanks.

Comment: Because you title says "Ubuntu" and your tag says "Kubuntu" please include results of: `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 mounted drives no longer show up in Nautilus by default. They need to defined as "bookmarks".

You need to bookmark them and will likely want to rename the bookmark. This GIF illustrates the technique:

[image: Nautilus 18 bookmark.gif]

1. Pick a partition from your "Other Locations" list.
2. Click the upper right "hamburger"  (☰) menu.
3. From the dropdown menu click the center menu button to bookmark it.
4. Move to the new sidebar entry and rename it from the mount name ("c" in my example) to something more meaningful ("Windows 10 SSD" in my example).

Comment: Something else to check is "Show in User Interface": https://askubuntu.com/questions/858029/how-to-disable-access-to-win7-disk-partitiondual-boot/858225#858225

Comment: Another thing to check out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043472/stacked-icons-of-network-mounts-on-desktop

Comment: Kubuntu Dolphin file manager specific: https://www.lifewire.com/kubuntu-how-to-2202589

Comment: Because kubuntu is based on KDE there is also this: [Show Mounted Devices on KDE desktop](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/show-mounted-devices-on-kde-desktop/91258)

Comment: If you look at the gif above and as I told you I can't see even drives to go in and clicking on them.

Comment: Check the first link "show in user interface"

Comment: Does it sound like this is same problem? https://askubuntu.com/q/1188500/307523