# After Xubuntu upgrade to 19.10, some apps can't see my external HD, but Thunar can

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 19.10

After I upgraded to 19.10, my Xubuntu system works fine EXCEPT that some apps, like the browser and applications that want to set a folder to save files, don't see the external drive, as if they don't have permission or something.

If I try and view the drive contents myself, I can see it and access it via the [Thunar file manager of Xubuntu](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/the-file-manager-window), with no problem; but  when I try to save files from within installed apps, they don't even see the drive in the /media folder.

The owner of the drive and group are both set to the user and not root. Nothing about this came up when I searched this site, and there's not a lot of answers to this specifically on Google. I have no idea what to do; how may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: https://sourcedigit.com/16391-change-ownership-set-write-permission-on-ext4-partition-in-linux-ubuntu/ shows how to change ownership to root.

Comment: Does this sound like same problem? https://askubuntu.com/q/1188287/307523

Comment: Are the applications in question installed as snaps? You can check with `snap list`.

Comment: @mook765, yes one was, bitcoin-core. and it did not have a permissions tab in the software store thingy. Chromium did and changing the permissions fixed its permissions issues. I found out that snap does not allow the apps to access drives outside of the home user, or something, so I just removed all snap apps. pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what ending up solving this for me was to actually just change the owner from the USER to ROOT. and then , as counter intuitively as it may sound, then there were no more permission errors and all is fine. :-)